# What does Flickr use for charting?

Tags: javascript, charts, components, client-side, flickr

Recently I was browsing my Flickr account and the stats for it and noticed that they display a very nice chart. What made an impression on me was that it was rendered in HTML and used JavaScript for mouseover effects. Does anyone know if they used some third party charting component, or if they did it in-house? If they did use something, what was it?

Even if you don't know about Flickr specifically, can you recommend some charting components that use JavaScript or some JS library as opposed to Silverlight, Flash and other RIA technologies?

Answer (score 1):

Afraid I don't know about Flickr charts but here are some JavaScript ones

JavaScript;
http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/

Jquery;
http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Flickr uses (quick glance at source doesn't give any clues), but you might find the [Google Visualisation API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html) useful.